# Remove extra parameters from Swagger

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

Implemented Swagger in the project on Spring boot. Faced such a problem as a lot of extra parameters in the list of swagger-ui parameters. The controllers work directly with entities inside which there are ManyToOne and OneToMany fields, or with filters extended from entities, as a result of linking there is an abundance of completely unnecessary parameters for testing api.

Entity example:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Biometric {

public enum Type {
    SECURITY,
    CAMERA
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Id", example = "0")
private Long id;

@Column
@ApiParam(hidden = true)
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Token", example = "")
private String token;

@Column
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Name", example = "")
private String name;

@Column
@ApiModelProperty(value = "State", example = "")
private Boolean state;

@Column
@ApiParam(hidden = true)
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Version", example = "")
private String version;

@Column
@ApiParam(hidden = true)
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Number of users", example = "0")
private Long users;

@Column
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Type")
private Type type;

@ManyToOne
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Company", example = "")
private Company company;
}
```

Here I tried to hide some parameters that are insignificant for testing, such as the token and version using @ApiParam, but this kind of focus will not work with complex types.

Filter example:

```
public class BiometricFilter extends Biometric {

@ApiModelProperty(value = "City", example = "0")
private City city;


@ApiModelProperty(value = "Идентификатор района", example = "0")
private District district;
}
```

And finally, an example controller:

```
ApiOperation(value = "", response = Biometric.class, responseContainer = "List")
@GetMapping
public Result get(Pageable pageable, BiometricFilter biometricFilter, ServletRequest request) {

    return new Result(true, biometricRepo.findAll(BiometricSpec.find(biometricFilter), pageable));
}
```

After intensive googling, I came to the conclusion that the only more or less working option is to rebuild the controllers to work with DTO objects, in which the nested classes are replaced with simple identifier types, but this means that I will have to rebuild a lot of controllers (
Actually, the question is: is there a way to do without rebuilding the controllers, or are my assumptions true, and I have to rebuild a bunch of controllers?

Warning questions, yes, switching to swagger is required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Swagger API and later OpenAPI Specification for many years. And earlier I tried to use the SpringFox for automatic building of Swagger file. It's very flexible - on any change we have an updated version of Swagger file.

But I faced with few issues in this approach: Spring is developing much faster than SpringFox, annotations cannot cover all requirements to the final Swagger file, the final implementation of Swagger file is not optimized and very 'straight' and 'dummy'. Besides, plenty of non-functional code (annotations) in functional classes is not a good approach.

And I finished using SpringFox, using only Swagger UI Editor. My Swagger files became more flexible, with more high-level architecture, without unnecessary trash, more 'laconic'. And the functional code is cleaner.

I understand that my advice does not solve your issue but it's just advice, I used automatic tools 4-5 years but returned to manual building of the Swagger file ))

Comment: I'll think about this option. Thanks alot for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Which Spring/Swagger version are you using? And how did you declare your swagger config? Personally i used the configuration annotation like this

```
    package com.application.swagger;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerSpringMvcPlugin() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com"))
          .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
          .build();                                        
    }

}
```

My apis also work with some entities but i don't see all the parameters in the swagger ui. Hope this helps